# What will be the nature of this group?

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group of order $10$. Then which one satisfies?
$(a)$ G is an abelian group $(b)$ G is a cyclic group $(c)$ there is a normal proper subgroup $(d)$ none of these

Comment: If it's abelian, it has to be cyclic, because $10$ factors only as $2\times5$, and $(\mathbb Z/2)\times(\mathbb Z/5)$ is cyclic since it's generated by $(1,1)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I've up-voted the question and all three of the answers that appear here so far, and I'm the only one who's voted so far. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Cauchy's theorem, any group of order $10$ contains an element of order $5$, which generates a subgroup of order $5$, which is of index $2$, and thus normal. As others above have indicated, the subgroup:

$\langle (1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5), (2\ 5)(3\ 4)\rangle$ of $S_5$ has order $10$, and is non-abelian.

Answer (score 3):

There are only two groups of order 10, the cyclic one and the dihedral.  Both contain a normal proper subgroup.

Comment: Is there (as I suspect) a quick way to show that no other non-abelian group of order $10$ exists? (That no other abelian group of order $10$ exists is what I showed in my comment under the question.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry, I think it should be easy to show that, but I haven't found a simple proof.  There are complex web pages and articles that classify small groups but there should be a simple proof just in the case of order 10.

Comment: @MichaelHardy by the sylow theorems, a non-abelian group of order $10$ has $5$ sylow $2$-subgroups (if there is only one, we can prove our group is iso. to $C_2 \times C_5$).. Fix one of these, call it $H$. Since the sylow $5$-subgroup is (iso. to) $C_5$, it's automorphism group is iso. to $C_4$. There is exactly ONE non-trivial homomorphism $H \to \text{Aut}(C_5)$ (we can take the action of $H$ on $C_5$ to be conjugation, since $C_5 \lhd G$), so exactly one (non-direct) semi-direct product $C_5 \rtimes H \cong C_5 \rtimes C_2 \cong D_5$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the dihedral group of order 10 is not abelian.